# How Do I Send Emails Using Python 3.4 With GMail?

Tags: python, email

I've been trying bits of code such as:

```
import smtplib

def sendemail(from_addr, to_addr_list, cc_addr_list,
              subject, message,
              login, password,
              smtpserver='smtp.gmail.com:587'):
    header  = 'From: %s\n' % from_addr
    header += 'To: %s\n' % ','.join(to_addr_list)
    header += 'Cc: %s\n' % ','.join(cc_addr_list)
    header += 'Subject: %s\n\n' % subject
    message = header + message

    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpserver)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(login,password)
    problems = server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr_list, message)
    server.quit()

sendemail(from_addr    = 'python@RC.net', 
        to_addr_list = ['example@gmail.com'],
        cc_addr_list = ['example@gmail.com'], 
        subject      = 'Howdy', 
        message      = 'Hello!', 
        login        = 'example@gmail.com', 
        password     = 'XXXX')
```

Except with an actual password and details.

It brings this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "User/Python/Email.py", line 27, in <module>
    password     = 'lollol69')
  File "User/Python/Email.py", line 15, in sendemail
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpserver)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 242, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 321, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 292, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 509, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 500, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Ideally, I could know what's wrong with the code and how I can fix this. If it's totally wrong then some working code with Gmail would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to split the smpt server address and the port and use them as separate parameters for `smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)` See https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/smtplib.html:

```
import smtplib

def sendemail(from_addr, to_addr_list, cc_addr_list,
              subject, message,
              login, password,
              smtpserver='smtp.gmail.com', smtpport=587):  # split smtpserver and -port
    header  = 'From: %s\n' % from_addr
    header += 'To: %s\n' % ','.join(to_addr_list)
    header += 'Cc: %s\n' % ','.join(cc_addr_list)
    header += 'Subject: %s\n\n' % subject
    message = header + message

    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpserver, smtpport)  # use both smtpserver  and -port 
    server.starttls()
    server.login(login,password)
    problems = server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr_list, message)
    server.quit()

sendemail(from_addr    = 'python@RC.net', 
        to_addr_list = ['example@gmail.com'],
        cc_addr_list = ['example@gmail.com'], 
        subject      = 'Howdy', 
        message      = 'Hello!', 
        login        = 'example@gmail.com', 
        password     = 'XXXX')
```

By the way: change your gmail password as it was posted in the stacktrace

Comment: That's not my actual password :) Thanks for the help will try this now.